# How to scroll to the bottom of a webpage using C# and Selenium Web Driver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Does anyone know how to create a method that will scroll to the bottom of the page?

I'm using VS Code and selenium web driver with C#. I can get the page to load but there are links at the bottom of the page I need to click onto. So I need a method that will scroll all the way to the bottom of the page.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send Javascript to the website. You can use this code to scroll to the bottom :

```js
let end_reached = false;
let pageTop = window.visualViewport.pageTop;
while (!end_reached){
    window.scrollBy(0, 100);
    end_reached = pageTop == window.visualViewport.pageTop
    pageTop = window.visualViewport.pageTop
}
```